# Any equivalent of c++ "delete this"?

Tags: objective-c

In C++ an object can delete itself, in Objective-C calling Dealloc is not something permitted, also with ARC the class may not even have a dealloc.

In Objective-C would be an equivalent way of an object deleting itself as is sometimes done in C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent for "delete this" as Objective-C uses reference counting and the system will delete your object when the number of its references reaches zero. If you want to implement some kind of "one-shot" objects i.e. that do something then delete themselves, then your best bet will be to increment the reference count to self when starting the operation with `[self retain]` and decrement it when you end with `[self release]`. If nobody else holds reference to your object, this later will cause the object to delete itself.

Answer (score 0):

Release the memory and delete it?

```
[xyz release];
xyz=nil;
```

Comment: [self autorelease]  or [self release]

Answer (score 0):

set your object to nil

```
obj = nil
```

Comment: Likewise as to my other comment, where is self in this?